# Filtration for List view data upon List view Header column clicks in WINFORMS

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, listview, c#-4.0

I dont know whether this is possible or not, But i just want your suggestions on this ..

Here is what I would like to be able to do. Not sure if this functionality is built in or if I will need to use a combination of any controls/tools.

I want to be able to filter a listview data.. have it filter the listview accordingly on click of listview columns header.I want to be able to use checkboxes in dropdown of listview header column such that I can filter data easily.

Best Example: Control Panel-->Uninstall a Program ,Where a list of uninstall programs available in listview for computing filtration upon click of any header.

I want this in Windows Forms Applications C# Visual Studio 2010

If solution is possible, pls. share the site links or any free tools also as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same idea for a `DataGridView` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup However, you would have to write the code to do the filtering as a winforms `ListView` does not supporting binding to a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) -- an open source wrapper around a .NET ListView -- supports filtering out of the box.

[image: Filtering]